# Issue with repmgr's reported version during PostgreSQL 12 switchover

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

**PostgreSQL12 problem when switchover with repmgr 5.3.2.**

Hello everyone,
I have a problem when perform swithover with repmgr.
I have 2 servers, primary and standby.

When running the following command:
`/usr/pgsql-12/bin/repmgr standby swithover -f /etc/repmgr/12/repmgr.conf --dry-run`

It outputs the following error:
`NOTICE: checking switchover on node "Repmgr1"(ID: 1) in --dry-run mode INFO: SSH connection to host "10.172.55.30" succeeded ERROR : unable to parse "repmgr"'s reported version on "10.172.55.30"`

Anyone used to meet this problem or know how to fix it?